# Magento: Subscription start date should be greater than current date

Tags: magento, paypal

In Magento 1.9.0.1 I want customers to accept Terms and Conditions before placing a recurring payment order via Paypal express.

When I place the order on the final step, get this error: Subscription start date should be greater than current date (#11505: Start Date should be greater than current date).

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thanks :-)

Comment: this looks like it has been answered [in the question posted here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8067/subscription-start-date-should-be-greater-than-current-date).

As suggested there check your server time and timezone settings.